# Installing only specific dependencies with --pre flag

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setuptools, setup.py

- My team works on packages "A" and "B".
- Package "A" depends on package "B" but also depends on package "C" which is 3rd party.
- I am working on package "A" pre-release version and want to install all of its pre-release dependencies belonging to the same team. I simply run `pip install . --pre --upgrade` (it works, because the dependencies are specified in `setup.py`) and I suddenly find out that `--pre` flag was propagated to a 3rd party dependency "C". And I don't want that - I only want to install **my** pre-releases.

***Question**: what would be the most sensible way to distinguish internal/external dependencies?*

---

P.S. I have thought of some solutions, but they do not seem very elegant.

*Solution 1: Use two requirement.txt files. One will contain internal dependencies and will be run with `--pre` flag. Another will contain 3rd party dependencies and will be run without the flag.*

Comment: Did you ever find another solution to this? dealing with the same issue.